# How to convert nullable variable to non nullable type?

Tags: php, string, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

I have function which will receive parameter `?string`

```
public function func(?string $x): string
{
    $x = trim(strtolower($x));
    $x = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $x);
    $x = str_replace(' ', '-', $x);
    return $x;
}
```

running `./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse` give those errors:

```
Parameter #1 $str of function strtolower expects string, string|null given.              
Parameter #3 $subject of function preg_replace expects array|string, string|null given.  
Parameter #3 $subject of function str_replace expects array|string, string|null given.
```

`strtolower` needs `string` and `preg_replace`&`str_replace` need `array|string` 
what is the best way to solve this without changing param from `?string $x` to `string $x`?
in otherwords how to change var type from `string|null` to `string` ?

Comment: What does the ? At the type declaration do? Got a reference to the manual, maybe?

Comment: the ? was introduced in PHP 7.1 its a "nullable type" it is conveniently at the top of the new features list for PHP 7.1 http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: Is there a reason why this function even accepts a nullable?  Should it?  Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @Devon yes this is not the real function it's just an example, the real one accepts param string which returns from some object method which returns nullable strings. anyway solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be able to typecast your value of `$x`,

example:

```
function foo(?string $x) : string {
    $a = (string) $x;

    return $a;
}
```

This should yield,

```
var_dump(foo("test"));

string(4) "test"
```

And,

```
var_dump(foo(null));

string(0) ""
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: i already tried this way before but not work. infact i detect the problem now i have 2 `preg_replace` one after another , `preg_replace` returns string|array so it reverts the casting again.. anyway thank you your comment let me give this way another try :)

Comment: Hi, this is because your first function strtolower will return a null value if the string is empty. You would need to typecast for both strtolower and str_replace.

Answer (score 3):

While PHP can convert null to an empty string with casting, you really have to ask yourself why this function should even accept a null value in the first place.

If null means you have some default value for `$x`, then that seems perfectly logical, and you can use null coalescing to make `$x` the default string value if `$x` is null.

```
$x = $x ?? 'default';
```

However, the above could be more effectively resolved by defining 'default' in the signature:

```
function func(string $x = 'default')
```

But based on your code, there really isn't any reason for null to be passed to this function.  In my opinion, that's a code smell and should not be allowed.  This function only works with strings, so don't allow nulls to begin with.  The null value should then be handled before it reaches this function, by the consumer.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one :)